# Flutter bottom Navigator gesture detector not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I made a custom bottom navigator with icons being a separate widget, the custom navigator bar is present at the bottom of the pageview. On swipe, the pages change so do the color of the icons but I can't change the pages by clicking on the icons also logout button is not working. This is the code for the custom bottom navigator with the separate widget for items within the bottom custom navigation bar

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart'as firebase_auth;

import 'package:flutter_fashion/main.dart';


class CustomBottomNavigator extends StatefulWidget {

  final int tab;
  final Function(int) tabPressed;
  const CustomBottomNavigator({Key? key, required this.tab, required this.tabPressed}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomBottomNavigatorState createState() => _CustomBottomNavigatorState();
}

class _CustomBottomNavigatorState extends State<CustomBottomNavigator> {
  int _selectedTab=0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _selectedTab=widget.tab;
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(12), topRight: Radius.circular(12)),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.05),
                spreadRadius: 1.0,
                blurRadius: 30.0)
          ]),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          CustomBottomNavigatorItem(
            icon: Icons.home_outlined,
            selected: _selectedTab==0?true:false,
            onPressed: () {
              widget.tabPressed(0);
            },
          ),
          CustomBottomNavigatorItem(
            icon: Icons.code_rounded,
            selected: _selectedTab==1?true:false,
            onPressed: () {
              widget.tabPressed(1);
            },
          ),
          CustomBottomNavigatorItem(
            icon: Icons.bookmark_border_rounded,
            selected: _selectedTab==2?true:false,
            onPressed: () {
              widget.tabPressed(2);
            },
          ),
          CustomBottomNavigatorItem(
            icon: Icons.logout_rounded,
            selected: _selectedTab==3?true:false,
            onPressed: () {
              firebase_auth.FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
              Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (builder) => MyApp()),
                      (route) => false);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


class CustomBottomNavigatorItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  final bool selected;
  final Function onPressed;
  CustomBottomNavigatorItem(
      {required this.icon, required this.selected, required this.onPressed,});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool _selected = selected;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => onPressed,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 28),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(
                top: BorderSide(
                    color: _selected
                        ? Theme.of(context).accentColor
                        : Colors.transparent,
                    width: 2.0))),
        child: Icon(
          icon,
          size: 24,
          color: _selected ? Theme.of(context).accentColor : Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onPressed` isn't called. The parentheses are missing. Either use:

```
onTap: () => onPressed(),
```

or

```
onTap: onPressed,
```